# What is the difference between angularFire() and $firebase()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

In the angularfire website,

```
function MyController($scope, $firebase) {
    var peopleRef = new Firebase("https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/people");
    $scope.people = $firebase(peopleRef);
```

But in the todomvc [source code](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/gh-pages/examples/todomvc/js/controllers/todoCtrl.js),

```
function TodoCtrl($scope, $location, angularFire, filterFilter) {
    var url = "https://angularFire.firebaseio.com/todomvc";
    var promise = angularFire(url, $scope, 'todos');
```

Why are the APIs different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angularfire website reflects the new API. The todomvc source code still uses the old.

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/_F_n5yCn_EA)

Comment: Specifically, todomvc uses version 0.5 of angularFire. In 0.6, the API underwent a drastic simplification and cleanup process. angularFire and $firebase are roughly equivalent (the same service) just different versions.

Comment: We'll be updating the TODOMVC example to match the new API in the coming weeks.